# All ios devices have UDID?

Tags: objective-c, udid

Recently i just update my app and notice my database data and itunesconnect Sales and Trends report not matched! The report show my app got 24k of updates but in my database only captured 6k of udid, do you guys have any ideas whats wrong ? IOS no longer support UDID ?

below is my script to capture UDID:

> -- (NSString *)getUDID {
>
> ```
> return [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: If you're sending UDID data to your server, it could be that the user wasn't connected to the internet at the time of application use.

Comment: should not be so large amount! 24k and 6k! is it possible they cant run the app after update? but i dont receive any report from users.

Comment: I think i know why already, i guess users never run my app after they download.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are not alowed to access that property any longer. Even if 3rd party libs like Phonegap 1.5 have such a call built in, it could lead to a reject of your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many users keep and still update apps that they never use after the first day, or few days, of trying them out.  They apparently don't delete apps from iTunes on their Mac or PC, and hit "Update All", including all those apps which they never run and/or in which they have no interest anymore.

It looks like only 25% of the customers who have downloaded and still update your app, actually still use it.  Maybe even less, as a single active customer might have multiple devices, each with a unique UDID.  Or perhaps that's the percentage that uses your app regularly (maybe they might run it for the first time after updating next week).

Answer (score 2):

From the doc:
uniqueIdentifier:

> An alphanumeric string unique to each device based on various hardware
>   details. (read-only) (Deprecated in iOS 5.0. Instead, create a unique
>   identifier specific to your app.) Do not use the uniqueIdentifier
>   property. To create a unique identifier specific to your app, you can
>   call the CFUUIDCreate function to create a UUID, and write it to the
>   defaults database using the NSUserDefaults class.

Comment: What does this actually answer? I can still run this on my iOS 5.1 device. Deprecated means it is marked for removal in an upcoming release not that it has already been removed.